# Error while launching FTL game

Tags: games, steam

I'm trying to start the game FTL: Faster than light on steam and I keep getting this error :

```
ExecCommandLine: "/home/fm0s/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam -foreground"
Game update: AppID 212680 "FTL: Faster Than Light", ProcID 9211, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/fm0s/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/fm0s/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
/home/fm0s/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/FTL Faster Than Light/FTL: line 4: cd: ./data: No such file or directory
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/fm0s/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/fm0s/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/fm0s/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/fm0s/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/fm0s/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/fm0s/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Loading Arch = amd64
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/fm0s/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  39
  Current serial number in output stream:  40
No settings file found! 
Initializing Crash Catcher...
Initializing Video
Game removed: AppID 212680 "FTL: Faster Than Light", ProcID 9211 

`
```

I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

it is due to old stdlibc++ included in FTL {arch}/lib/libstdc++.so.6

delete or archive the file with

- cd ..sommedir../FTL/data
- mv ./amd64/lib/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6_unwanted_amd64_lib
- mv ./x86/lib/libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6_unwanted_x86_lib